# Help with registerattached Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, attached-properties

I created my own DataGrid control which inherits from `DataGrid`. I declared a Dependency Property which I want to use at column level, so on the PreviewKeyDown event I check the value and decide if this current cell needs to be handled or not.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static DependencyProperty HandleKeyPressEventProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "HandleKeyPressEvent",
           typeof(bool),
           typeof(MyDataGrid),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

    public bool HandleKeyPressEvent
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (HandleKeyPressEvent)
        {
            HandleKeyPress(e);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
<MyDataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid">
   <DataGridTextColumn MyDataGrid.HandleKeyPressEvent = "True" />
   <DataGridTemplateColumn MyDataGrid.HandleKeyPressEvent = "False"/>
</MyDataGrid>
```

But I am having a real problem to have this dependency property available at the column level. What I try to do is just like `Grid.Column`. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attached property has a static Get method and a static Set method (which are declared by the property name prefixed by Get/Set) instead of a CLR Property wrapper. To check the current column in `OnPreviewKeyDown`, you can use `CurrentCell.Column`

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HandleKeyPressEventProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HandleKeyPressEvent",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(MyDataGrid),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
    public static bool GetHandleKeyPressEvent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty);
    }
    public static void SetHandleKeyPressEvent(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty, value);
    }
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetHandleKeyPressEvent(CurrentCell.Column) == true)
        {
            HandleKeyPress(e);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```